# Why does bash print exit even when it does not exit - is this a bug?

Tags: bash, exit

exit with zero or one numeric argument like `exit` or `exit 42` print "exit" and exit the shell.

exit with an invalid argument like `exit hello` prints an error message, prints "exit" and exits the shell with return value 255.

exit in a pipe, for example `exit | cat | exit` does not print "exit" and the return value of this command depends on which version of bash we're using. This does not exit the shell.

exit with multiple arguments, like, `exit 1 2 3` prints an error message, prints "exit" but does not exit the shell.

This means that sometimes bash will print "exit" without actually exiting, which can be very confusing.
Is this a bug or does this make sense for some reason?

Comment: @jesse_b, I can with 5.1, and with the current code from the development repository

Comment: Disregard me I have a function replacing the normal exit command that disregards any additional arguments, I was using `\exit` but I guess that didn't work.  `command exit` reproduces

Comment: `exit hello world` and `exit foo 1` will error but still exit so it seems only if the first argument is a valid number will it run into this.

Answer (score 0):

Bash prints "exit" when it is about to exit a non-login shell, and prints "logout" (or equivalent in a locale used) when it is about to exit a login shell. Therefore I guess that this message is printed exactly to distinguish these two cases from user point of view (when you log out from eg. a ssh session to a remote system and return to the local one, such an information may be helpful, if your system prompt does not include the hostname).

The case you mentioned (`exit 1 2 3`), where bash prints "exit" but does not exit (and prints an error message instead, **after** printing "exit") should be considered a design error, I think. `exit` should parse arguments and print an optional error message before printing "exit" or "logout". The latter should be printed only in case of a successful parameter check. You can file a bug if you think this is confusing.

Comment: Is there a way to find out if it has already been reported?